# ES6 way to define state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'd like to use state this way:

```
class Checkout extends Component {
    state = {
        ingredients: null,
        totalPrice: 0
    };
```

But I'm getting error saying `Unexpected token =`, I know this can be fixed with **babel-plugin-transform-class-properties**, unfortunately it's not working in my case.
Here is my **package.json**

```
"babel": {
    "presets": [
      "env",
      "react-app"
    ],
    "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.1.0"
  }
```

Any idea what else can be wrong here?

Comment: Is it babel that is throwing the error, or your browser. It looks like it should be working as long as it is getting transpiled.

Comment: @samanime AFAIK that's Babel throwing this.

Comment: Can you add the full output from Babel of your error running against a small example (like the one you shared)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was related to `Eslint`.
When I installed `babel-eslint` and add parcer option to `.eslintrc`, this error gone.

```
"parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
            "jsx": true
        },
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
```

Comment: I believe you can omit `experimentalObjectRestSpread` option. And set `ecmaVersion`.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to do what you want is to set `this.state` in a constructor:

```
class Checkout extends Component {
    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            // Whatever keys and values you want here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is an ES6 syntax (currently stage 3) which he's trying to use via Babel: [class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields)

Comment: which is often preferred if there is no need to use props in constructor, as it avoids the need to invoke the function and removes clutter like the necessary `super(props)` call, in this case

Comment: samanime is right, i wasnt familiar. But it exists: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#field-declarations

Comment: While this will work it isnt the es6 field declaration he's looking for.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I would, but I believe what he's posted should work, which means there is some error that can't be identified solely by what he posted. I've asked for additional info. If he posts it and I can spot the info, I'll be sure to post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try [babel-preset-stage-2](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-2/). It includes `transform-class-properties` and other stuff. And add it to your babel `presets` array

```
"babel": {
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "react-app",
    "stage-2"
  ]
}
```

This will allow you to define `state` ES6 way.

Also the recommended way to enable babel presets is via `.babelrc` file. It should be placed in the project root.

Comment: Try to use `.babelrc` as it's recommended on their site.

Comment: Using one or the other should all be the same. Same as using `stage-2` or using the transform directly. It all ultimately resolves the same way.

Comment: Friends don't let friends using stage-X presets in real apps.

Comment: Stage presets are not reliable by its nature. It is a draft (WIP implementation) for a draft (TC39 _proposals_). Ideally, `preset-env` + handpicked plugins should be used. Trusted source: http://2ality.com/2017/02/babel-preset-env.html